# sizeof parameter pack in a template template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a struct that accepts a template template argument like so

```
template <template <typename...Args> typename T>
struct foo {
    static size_t get_count() {
        // ... implementation here
    }
};
```

Inside foo, I want to count the number of template arguments `T` accepts. So the following calls should return 1 and 2 respectively.

```
template <typename T>
struct bar1{};
template <typename T, typename S>
struct bar2{};

foo<bar1>::get_count(); // = 1
foo<bar2>::get_count(); // = 2
```

I have tried `sizeof...(Args)` but that doesn't work, because `Args...` is not really a template argument to `foo`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Since a **tuple** can do it with [`std::tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size), I presume it is possible.

Comment: @Eljay the issue is std::tuple_size accepts an instantiation of the template not the template itself. I think I know how to implement that

Comment: I want to be able to do it with just the template

Comment: What would you expect it to return if the template used as argument also is variadic?

Comment: @user17732522 yes, that is a special case I was hoping I could write a partial specialization for which say returns -1.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Are you asking for before C++20 or after? I think constraints from C++20 will make this difficult to do in general.

Comment: `Args` are parameters of `T`. This is `T`'s responsibility to provide `foo` with a count or parameters.

Comment: @user17732522 either would be okay, but before would be slightly preferable since my code base so far is all C++11 compatible

Comment: @273K I understand that is a way, but it would be intrusive to T. I was hoping for something as a trait. Also I really can't call static functions from T since I can't even instantiate it

Comment: One [limited solution](https://godbolt.org/z/v43jc38ja) is to check if `T` can be instantiated with `<>`, `<void>`, `<void, void>`, ... and then count the number of `void`s.

Comment: @Evg interesting! So use `std::enable_if` with `decltype(T<void, void..>)` (increasing number of voids)?

Comment: It's almost trivial with Boost.Mp11. Implementation of `mp_valid` is also simple with `void_t` trick.

Comment: @Evg got it! I will try it with `void_t`. Don't want to have boost as a dependency. If you could write it up as an answer, I can accept it. My guess is detecting variadic templates this way would not be possible

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399030/counting-parameters-of-a-template-template-type

Comment: The dupe has good solutions in it. One more [solution](https://godbolt.org/z/oPb5sK8E9) without Boost dependency.